# Android aws CognitoUserSession.getIdToken() is giving null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services

This is the line where always getting error

```
        String sess = "workid_token=" + AppHelper.getCurrSession().getIdToken().getJWTToken() + ";base_token=" + AppHelper.getCurrSession().getRefreshToken().getToken() + ";" + getsess + ";";
```

I am implementing amazon web services in my android app.After implementation i am always getting error in the above line please help me to sort this issue

Answer (score 0):

You should do login (create a session) before getting tokens. You can take a look to this link: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoYourUserPoolsDemo